# Old BIOS motherboard doesn't recognize HDD

Tags: motherboard, bios

I'm trying to start an old M537 motherboard, if I connect an HDD take some seconds trying to detect it and then fails HDD NONE.
If I connect a CD-ROM it detect it very fast.

I also tried with different cables and two IDE one old 1.65GB Caviar and one 60GB WD600.

Also the floppy is detected but doesn't turn the light on when is booting.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Don't forget ATA/IDE drives have master/slave jumpers set, make sure that you have the correct jumper setting depending on if you have other devices in the chain.   I find Cable Select is usually good, but I have also encountered situations where I needed to set master/slave explicitly on older hardware.  Also, what does your BIOS say if you go into the settings?   Try to set BIOS to auto detect drives, some old BIOSes are rather fickle when it comes to mismatching settings.   Try setting BIOS settings to factory default to see if you get any different results.

Comment: Also does the computer make any clicking or grinding sounds when it tries to access the hard disk?   Is the hard disk spinning up (the disk will feel like it is slightly humming, meaning the platters are spinning inside).    Since this is an older HDD that you are working with, it could very well be faulty/dead - so keep that in mind too..

Comment: If the motherboard is really old, it is possible the BIOS will not recognize your HDD. A BIOS update is required to support newer models, but its possible there simply is no update to support this harddrive.

Comment: @Richie086 I tried with one HDD or CD at a time as Master and Slave mode. The Disk are ok, I connect those HDDs to a newer PC with a USB-IDE adaptor and directly with another motherboard and works ok both of them. I will try to set to factory.

Comment: The old 1.65GB Caviar it was connected to this motherboard about 14 years ago, so I think it should work.